# how to make ascending id in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

this code not asceding id. we have id 1, 2, 3, 15. when adding next record is read id 16. so how to solve this problem ? id must 1,2,3,4,5,etc

```
    <?php
include"class_koneksi.php";
$db=new database();
$db->konek();


    if(empty($_GET['aksi'])){

        $daftar=$db->tampilData();
            echo"<table border=1>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Nama</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Pesan</td>
                    <td>Edit</td>
                    <td>Hapus</td>
                </tr>";
        foreach($daftar as $data){
            echo" <tr>
                    <td>".$data['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$data['nama']."</td>
                    <td>".$data['email']."</td>
                    <td>".$data['pesan']."</td>
                    <td><a href='?aksi=edit&id=$data[id]'>edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href='?aksi=hapus_data&id=$data[id]'>Hapus</a></td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo"</table> <br> <a href='?aksi=tambah'>TAMBAH</a>";


    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){
        echo"<br>
        <form method=POST action='?aksi=tambah_data'>
            <table>

                <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        ";

    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah_data'){
        $id= isset($_POST['id']);
        $nama=$_POST['nama'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pesan=$_POST['pesan'];
        $db->tambahData($id,$nama,$email,$pesan);

    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='edit'){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        echo"<br>
            <form method=POST action='?aksi=update_data'>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Id</td><td><input type=text name='id' value='".$db->bacaData('id',$id)."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama' value='".$db->bacaData('nama',$id)."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email' value='".$db->bacaData('email',$id)."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan' value='".$db->bacaData('pesan',$id)."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
                </table>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData('id',$id)."'>
            </form>
        ";

    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='update_data'){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $nama=$_POST['nama'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pesan=$_POST['pesan'];
        $db->updateData($id,$nama,$email,$pesan);

    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='hapus_data'){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $db->hapusData($id);
    }

?>
```

can you tell me where this code wrong?
can you help me solve this problem? thanks

Comment: You know what, i would really love to help you out but when i saw that your code is not indented properly i could not continue reading your code!

Comment: This might [help](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/p/SQL_order_by.htm)

Comment: Why do you consider this "A Problem"?

Comment: you net set id auto_increment in your database.. that will be asceding automaticly

Comment: i has been set id auto_increment in databases but still not ascending

Answer (score 2):

Remove the auto increment property of the table which is showing 16.

Before inserting a new row in that table write a select query.

```
$sql = "select * from `table_name`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$id=count($result)+1;
if(count($result)>0){
   $temp = 1;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       if($row['id']!=$temp++){
           $id=$temp; break;
       }

   }
}

$sql = "insert into `table_name` (`id`,`..`,`..`) values('"$id.."','..','..')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I hope this will solve your query...

Comment: function tampilData(){
$sql = "select * from tb_barang";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$id=count($result)+1;
if(count($result)>0){
   $data = 1;
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       if($rows['id']!=$data++){
           $id=$data; break;
       }

   }
}

$sql = "insert into tb_barang(id,nama,email,pesan)values('$id','$nama','$email','$pesan')";
mysql_query($sql);

Comment: try to use back-quotes...like .. $sql = "insert into `\`tb_barang\`` (`\`id\``,`\`nama\``,`\`email\``,`\`pesan\``) values('$id','$nama','$email','$pesan')"; and if error still persist, print the query and run the printed query in the phpmyadmin sql editor and see wat error it gives..

Answer (score 0):

It is showing id as 16 becouse in table properties Id is set as auto increment

Comment: i has been set id auto_increment in databases but still not ascending. can you see edited may be in table code is wrong?

Comment: if you add rows and delete them the auto increment number wont be reset.. you will always get a unique id that you have never use for this table ever with auto increment. unless you can reset it from the mysql server. but not recommenced..

Answer (score 0):

First remove auto increment from id in the respective database table you are having this issue. Then Replace this code section with your code.

```
.
.
.
elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){
        $daftar=$db->tampilData();
        $id=count($daftar)+1;
        if(count($daftar)>0){
           $temp = 1;
           forech($daftar as $row){
               if($row['id']!=$temp++){
                   $id=$temp; break;
               }

           }
        }
        echo"<br>
        <form method=POST action='?aksi=tambah_data'>
            <table>

                <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama'><input type="hidden" name='id' value="<?php echo $id ?>"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        ";

    }elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah_data'){
        $id= $_POST['id'];
        $nama=$_POST['nama'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pesan=$_POST['pesan'];
        $db->tambahData($id,$nama,$email,$pesan);

    }
.
.
.
```

I hope this solves your requirement..